# Adding image_picker dependency Error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I am trying to add image picker dependency in Flutter, I get the following error:

> Error on line 22, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
>
> image_picker: ^0.4.10
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you named your package/application `image_picker`, and now `pub` can't tell it apart from the acutal `image_picker` already published that you want.

Double check the `name` property in your `pubspec.yaml`, and make sure it's **not** `image_picker` (or any other existing pub package name for that matter).

But please post your full `pubspec.yaml`, or even better a minimally complete reproduction of this issue if that's not the case.

Comment: Hey @Dan thanx for writing back, Here is my pubspec.yml file: https://pastebin.com/WiGz8JaU

Comment: Hey thanx  man you save my day. You were right i have name my app image_picker thats why  i am getting the error